# Writing queries in Kibana search bar

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I could perform the delete operation on log lines using the sense plugin. The same syntax doesn't work in Kibana. How do we write queries in the Kibana search bar to delete data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kibana is read-only.  Try one of the other plugins (sense, es-head, etc).

Comment: I have tried sense. In "Splunk" app framework we can write queries in the search bar to perform delete operation as well (assuming you know splunk). So thought there might be something similar to that in kibana.